# How do I refer to something in a question?

Tags: english-to-german

I'm discussing a picture of a shop in the comments section, and I want to ask a question:

> Where can I find this shop?

Should I translate it like this:

> Wo kann ich das Geschäft finden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mit "das":**

Wo kann ich das in dem Bild dargestelle Geschäft finden?

**Ansonsten besser "dieses"**

Wo ist dieses Geschäft?

Wo finde ich dieses Geschäft?

Kennt jemand dieses Geschäft?

Comment: Was ist daran besser?

Answer (score 0):

Eine bessere Formulierung wäre:

> Wo kann ich [dieses](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dieser) Geschäft finden?

Comment: What's wrong with OPs suggestion?

Comment: @Em1 ist es nicht `dieses` konkreter als `das`? Dass man genau für *dieses Geschäft* spricht, nich für Geschäfte überal?

Comment: @Al.G. Ich habe nix gegen "dieses", es ist auch die korrekte Übersetzung für "this", aber "das" ist nicht falsch und diese Antwort hier suggeriert, es wäre jedoch falsch.